# AxMSTSCLib an ActiveX component does not work for Window Server 2012 r2

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, remote-desktop

I am implementing a remote desktop application with C#.
I used AxMSTSCLib an ActiveX component for remote desktop connection.

I used AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7 to establish remote desktop connection.

--Code to connect with remote desktop connection--

```
AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7 rdpProductionNode = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7();
rdpProductionNode.connect();
```

That code work well when I tried to connect other window.

But, the does not work well, if I tried to connect Window Server 2012 r2.
It does not show remote desktop screen.

Actually, it connected to Window Server 2012 r2.
But, it disconnected immediately.

I have no idea what is happening.
Would you all please help me.

Comment: The control reports mishaps through events, OnWarning, OnLogonError, OnFatalError.  Since you don't subscribe any of them, you can't find out why "it doesn't work".

Comment: Ah! I miss that point. I will try OnWarning, OnLogonError, OnFataError. Thank you Hans Passant!